# Multiple applications quit unexpectedly (Chrome, Evernote, Pages, etc)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash, applications

My OSX 10.8 works fine until today. Multiple applications quit unexpectedly, including Chrome, Evernote, Pages. It can't be fix even if I reopen or reinstall these apps.

I've conducted software update yesterday, not sure if it's one of the reasons. If I remember correctly, it's HP software or raw image processing, something like that, not a major system upgrade.

Anybody run into this problem? How did you solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve a general issue like this is to focus on one problem.

Pick one app (perhaps Pages, since you can get good Apple support on it if needed) and follow the typical troubleshooting steps.

Get a pen and paper and write down what you change:

- Reboot the machine and test that one app
- Reboot into safe mode and test that app
- Make a new user account and see if the problem happens there
- etc…

The pen and paper also help to note the time when things fail - so you can look over the logs or get trained help when you have exhausted the things you can address in troubleshooting.

If you don't have a good background on things to try, Apple has a nice article on how to troubleshoot:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1199

The real art here is how to decide it's software and not hardware.